# MPI - Asynchronous ring communication

Tags: c, asynchronous, buffer, mpi, send

I am trying to implement a simple `MPI` program where I call a function `foo()` on which `-n` processes pass around `n` arrays until all arrays have been passed to all processes(`n steps`). The implementation is in a form of ring communication where `process#0` sends to `process#2` and receives from `process#n-1` etc. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void foo(double* X, int n,int d,int k)
{
    int id, world_size;
    double *array = X;
    double *array_buff = malloc(n*d*sizeof(double));

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,  &id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Status status;

    array[0] = id;

    for(int step = 0 ; step < world_size ; step++)
    {
        int temp = id-step;
        if(temp<0)
        {
            temp = world_size+temp;
        }

        if(array[0]!= temp)
        {
            printf("[%d][%d] %f (start)\n", id, step, array[0]);
        }

        //even processes send first while odd process receive
        //first in order to avoid deadlock - achieve synchronization
        MPI_Request reqsend, reqrecv;
        int dst = (id+1)%world_size;
        if(id%2 == 0)
        {
            int src = id-1;
            if(id == 0)
            {
                src = world_size-1;
            }
            MPI_Isend(array, n*d, MPI_DOUBLE, dst, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqsend);
            MPI_Irecv(array_buff, n*d, MPI_DOUBLE, src, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqrecv);

        }
        else
        {

            MPI_Irecv(array_buff, n*d, MPI_DOUBLE, id-1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqrecv);
            MPI_Isend(array, n*d, MPI_DOUBLE, dst, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqsend);

        }   

        //..some array[] related work is been done here...           

        if(array[0]!=temp)
        {
            printf("[%d][%d] %f (end)\n", id, step, array[0]);
        }

        //update array asynchronously
        MPI_Wait(&reqrecv, &status);
        array = array_buff;
    }


    free(array);

}
```

In order to avoid deadlock *even numbered processes* send first and receive afterwards while *odd numbered processes* receive first and send afterwards.

The initialization: `array[0] = id;` aims to control whether the communication is done correctly. That's why I use two prints one at the begin and one at the end of my function in order to observe whether `array[]` changes contents before the `array = array_buff;` assignment (where `array[]` takes the buffered value) takes place.

One of the outputs I get is:

```
[0][2] 1.000000 (start)
[0][2] 1.000000 (end)
[0][3] 0.000000 (start)
[0][3] 0.000000 (end)
[1][3] 1.000000 (start)
[1][3] 1.000000 (end)
[3][1] 1.000000 (end)
[3][2] 0.000000 (end)
[3][3] 3.000000 (end)
```

**Why are the contents of `array[]` altered before the `array_buff[]` assignment?**

*Note*: I have read that in some MPI versions it's not ok to use `array[]` (the `Isend()` buffer) before the send has been completed. But I don't think that's the case here because even if I don't use `array[]` at all after the `Isend() Irecv()` segment the program behavior is still the same.

I have tried setting the **tags** to match each particular send, using an identifier value which is the **step value** but I get a deadlock and I don't get why. I would appreciate an explanation on that.
`tag = step;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `array = array_buff`. While `array[]` gets the correct values on the first step, after that when `array_buff` updates on the 2nd, 3rd etc step it changes the contents of `array[]` too as they point to the same memory.

The problem is solved with:

```
for(int i=0; i<n*d ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array_buff[i];
    }
```

Comment: It is also incorrect to modify `array` before `sendreq` completes.

Comment: As I mention on my question I have read that it is incorrect for certain lower versions of MPI. Isn't it?

Comment: No, this is always incorrect. If your message is "short enough", you might get lucky and not run into an issue (the message is sent in eager mode), but you cannot assume this is the behavior the MPI standard mandates.

Comment: Thank you I get it